# Angular pipe for returning BMI more than 30

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I wanted to have a pipe for returning how many items in an array that is greater than 30. The JSON array looks like this:

```
bmis = [
    {
        "bmi": 34.32
    },
    {
        "bmi": 23.75
    },
    {
        "bmi": 19.06
    },
    {
        "bmi": 18.69
    },
    {
        "bmi": 45.40
    },
    {
        "bmi": 37.64
    },
    {
        "bmi": 35.54
    }
]
```

Please note that those bmi values are fake for testing the result.

Then my bmi pipe is like below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'bmi'
})
export class BmiPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], attr: string): any {
        let counter = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i] >= 30.0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

And lastly, my template looks like this: `{{ bmis | bmi }}`

For saving spaces, I did not include component codes. Also, pipe is registered in the app.module file.
This pipe does not return 4 which is the correct result. In fact. it returns nothing.

I'm not sure the correctness of the pipe code. But I just can't see the missing part. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The items themselves aren't bigger than 30, they have a property that may be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code treats `bmis` array as its values are numbers, but they are in fact objects.
So, change this:

```
if (items[i] >= 30.0) {
    counter++;
}
```

To:

```
if (items[i].bmi >= 30.0) {
    counter++;
}
```